# MySQL tables USERS and FLASHCARDS - how to modify one depending on the other?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm implementing a flashcard app, hence my FLASHCARDS table contains fields such as QUESTION and RESPONSE, and my USERS table is just that - names and personal info of my flashcard app.

Here's where I get confused. The FLASHCARDS table will hold 100s of questions and responses categorized into "groups" of flashcards (or decks). When the USERS "use" the flashcards they will also be able to decide if the question was EASY, NORMAL, or DIFFICULT - hence modifying the time till the card is next shown.

If I only had one user this wouldn't be a problem - I'd just modify the FLASHCARDS table accordingly, but I´ll also have 100s of users. How can I modify FLASHCARDS table depending on each USERS decision of EASY, NORMAL or DIFFICULT and keep record of all of this for each user (I imagine in USERS table).

Comment: I disagree with the "close" votes. This question isn't too broad, it's a *particular* problem. It's possible that there are alternative "solutions" to the question, but those solutions are wrong. In terms of logical design of the database, there's only one "right" approach to solving this. As far as being "unclear", I fail to see how OP could have made the question any more clear. OP is in the process of developing a database model, and had a question. Sheesh.

Comment: Justin: **Welcome to the StackOverflow community!** We look forward to your thoughtful contributions! I think the question you asked is appropriate, and clearly presented. Please don't be discouraged by the members of the community that didn't understand your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a many-to-many relationship between the "Flashcard" entity and the "User" entity.

A particular "User" makes a decision about a particular "Flashcard".

A "User" can make a decision on zero, one or more "Flashcard".

A "Flashcard" can be decided by zero, one or more "User".

That's a classic many-to-many relationship.

In the relational model, we introduce a new relationship table, that establishes the relationship between "User" and "Flashcard"

As an example of what this table might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE user_flashcard
( user_id      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'fk ref user'
, flashcard_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'fk ref flashcard'
, decision     VARCHAR(30)           COMMENT 'EASY,NORMAL,DIFFICULT'
, PRIMARY KEY (user_id,flashcard)
, CONSTRAINT FK_user_flashcard_user 
     FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_user_flashcard_flashcard 
     FOREIGN KEY (flashcard_id) REFERENCES flashcard(id)
)
```

You could add additional attributes, for example: the last time the user viewed the flashcard, the number of times the user has viewed it.

You also need to consider whether this is just a pure relationship, or if this is might actually be an entity in your model.If we have repeating attributes, or any other entities might be related to this table, we'd likely want to introduce a simple primary key (`id`) that other tables can reference in a foreign key.

We also want to think about this, do we want a user to have more than one decision on a flashcard? Does `(user_id,flashcard_id)` need to be unique, or should it be non-unique.

The key to database design is data analysis. And one of the best tried-and-true techniques for "doing" data analysis is **Entity Relationship Modeling**.

---

**FOLLOWUP EXAMPLE DEMONSTRATION**

As a demonstration of how this "relationship" table works, I've created a very short SQL Fiddle, demonstrating the kind of questions that can be fairly easily answered using some fairly simple SQL.

[SQL Fiddle Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/090ee/5](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/090ee/5)

Comment: This is what I was going to write! Aside: typo, "Flaschard".

Comment: The `decision` could be an `ENUM` field.

Comment: Thank you spencer7593, your answer is much appreciated and it makes sense logically, i´ll need to spend a bit of time getting my head around it, i´m still a newbee and I haven´t implemented any relational table concepts before! Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Justin: No one was born with the skill to do database design. It takes time and effort, and it looks like you are making progress! Identify "Entities", people, place, thing, concept or event that can be uniquely identified and we need to store information about, and "Relationship" between those entities. By asking the right questions, "Can a Flashcard be decided by more than one User?" "Can a User decide more than one Flashcard?" We arrive at the cardinality of the relationships, 1-to-1, 1-to-many, 0or1-to-many, etc. And we resolve a many-to-many is by adding a table.

Comment: An example table, with some rows in it, really helps to get your head wrapped around it. And writing queries... "Which flashcards has a user decided on?" "Which flashcards did a user decide were EASY"? Which users decided a particular flashcard was DIFFICULT?, etc.

Comment: That SQL Fiddle is incredibly helpful, thank you so much Spencer. I appreciate you taking the time to do that for me!