# SQL many to many relation

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I’m using Wordpress quiz plugin. It has two tables (in fact more, but I’m trying to focus on the issue) – ‘questions’ and ‘questionpots’:

‘questions’: questionID ---- Question ---- potID

‘questionpots’: potID ---- potName

And the default query is:
$SQL = 'Select * FROM questions WHERE potID='.$potID;

So by default every question is assigned to a specific pot (‘potID’ in ‘questions’ table) and the relation is ‘one to many’. What I want to do is to assign questions to MORE than just one pot, so that for example the question “When did Rome fell?” would be asked whether someone choose “Rome history” pot OR “Ancient history” pot.

So I added the third table, ‘relations’, which matches questionIDs and potIDs.
The problem is I can’t figure out the query to select * from ‘questions’ WHERE potID='.$potID assuming that there’s one or MORE than one question for $potID.

How should I join this tables?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve a many-to-many relationship between two entities, we add a third table, a relationship table, with foreign keys referencing the two entity tables.

A row added to the relationship table represents a (wait for it...) *relationship* between the two entities.

As an example, assuming tables `question` and `pot` both have an `id` column as the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE question_pot
( question_id     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'fk ref question' 
, pot_id          INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'fk ref pot'
, PRIMARY KEY (question_id, pot_id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_question_pot_question 
     FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question(id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_question_pot_pot
     FOREIGN KEY (pot_id) REFERENCES pot(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

To add a relationship from `question id=444` to two pots `pot id=7` and `pot id=13`:

```
INSERT INTO question_pot VALUES (444,7), (444,13);
```

And scrap the `pot_id` column in the `question` table. You can save those first...

```
INSERT INTO question_pot (question_id, pot_id) 
SELECT q.id
     , q.pot_id
  FROM question q
 WHERE q.pot_id IS NOT NULL
;
```

And then drop the pot_id column from `question`.

---

If you've gotten that far, now you just need to perform JOIN operations...

To get all questions in `pot id=13`, for example:

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM question q
  JOIN question_pot r
    ON r.question_id = q.id
 WHERE r.pot_id = 13
```

**FOLLOWUP**

The query above gives an example of assigning an *alias* to a table, and using the alias to *qualify* column references.

Qualifying column references is best practice; it makes the statement easier for someone to read and interpret, without requiring them to lookup the definitions of the tables to figure out which column is coming from which table.

Compare the query above to this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM question
  JOIN question_pot
    ON question_id = id
 WHERE pot_id = 13
```

Now, try answering these questions: Is `id` a reference to a column from `question` or `question_pot`. (If this query is in a MySQL stored program (procedure, function, trigger), is the reference to `id` a reference to a column, or to a procedure variable.)

In some cases, we *have* to qualify column references to make the reference unambiguous, when the reference can refer to a column in multiple tables, and causes MySQL to throw an ambiguous column reference error.

It's possible to have a query working just fine, and then add a column to a table, e.g. adding `id` column to the `question_pot` table, and then the query will start failing with the "ambiguous column" error.

In my way of thinking, it's not acceptable that the addition of a column to a table should cause a "working" query to break. We can prevent that kind of error popping up in the future, simply by explicitly qualifying the column reference, even if it's not required right now.

As far as why we choose to use short aliases like `q` and `r` in place of just the table name.

In EXACTLY the same way you've identified the table names in your comment:

```
wp_ai_quiz_tblquestions    (=question)
wp_ai_quiz_tblquestionpots (=pot)
wp_ai_quiz_question_pot    (=question_pot)
```

I'm essentially saying the same thing with the table aliases:

```
wp_ai_quiz_tblquestions     (=q)
wp_ai_quiz_tblquestionpots  (=p)
wp_ai_quiz_question_pot     (=r)
```

Compare reading this:

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM wp_ai_quiz_tblquestions q
  JOIN wp_ai_quiz_question_pot r
    ON r.question_id = q.id
 WHERE r.pot_id = 13
```

To reading this:

```
SELECT wp_ai_quiz_tblquestions.*
  FROM wp_ai_quiz_tblquestions
  JOIN wp_ai_quiz_question_pot
    ON wp_ai_quiz_question_pot.question_id = wp_ai_quiz_tblquestions.id
 WHERE wp_ai_quiz_question_pot.pot_id = 13
```

Throw in a few more tables, and also don't line things up like I always line things up, and it requires *more effort* from the reader to decipher what the statement is doing. In really complicated queries, referencing half a dozen or more tables, I'll add comments above the query, explaining the usage of the aliases.

```
-- find all questions in a particular pot
-- q = question row to be returned from wp_ai_tblquestion 
-- r = relationship between question and pot to be searched
SELECT q.id
     , q.name
     , ...
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'fk ref question'
, pot_id      ID INT UNSIGN' at line 2

Comment: there's a spurious `ID` on two lines in the SQL, I don't know what i was thinking there, I'll fix that.  You'd also need to adjust the datatypes on the `question_id` and `pot_id` columns to match the primary keys in your tables, to get the foreign keys defined.

Comment: Here's a SQL Fiddle example of a many-to-many relationship (including an attribute on the relationship) and some sample/demonstration SQL [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/090ee/5](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/090ee/5).  This was prepared for a different question...  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405248/mysql-tables-users-and-flashcards-how-to-modify-one-depending-on-the-other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405248/mysql-tables-users-and-flashcards-how-to-modify-one-depending-on-the-other)

Comment: Ok, one step forward,  but now I get: #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint . "Adjust the datatypes"? You mean INT? In question table and pots table there's INT(11). Can NOT NULL make this problem? In question table and pots table I have Null>No, default>None

Comment: No, its not the NOT NULL.  SIGNED vs UNSIGNED makes a difference.  (We always make our `id` columns UNSIGNED... usually INT but sometimes BIGINT).  the datatype of the foreign key column must match EXACTLY.  Change the definition of the foreign key column to match the primary key that's being referenced, that's what I meant by "adjust the datatypes"...  that information wasn't provided in your question, so I used what we always used... recognizing that it might not match what you were using.

Comment: I changed to SIGNED and it works, now the query... :)

Comment: So now, forget about the `pot_id` on the `question` table establishing a relationship. (That's how we implement a one-to-many relationship, where a row in table is related to at most one row in another table.) Take a look at the SQL Fiddle example.

Comment: Ok, one last thing - what does q and r refers to? And if my tables are: wp_ai_quiz_tblquestions (=question), wp_ai_quiz_tblquestionpots (=pot) and wp_ai_quiz_question_pot (=question_pot) how the query should look like?

Comment: The `q` and `r` are *aliases* assigned to tables referenced in the FROM clause of the query, e.g. `FROM question q`. With the alias assigned, anywhere in the query I can unambiguously refer to a column from the `question` table by *qualifying* the column name with the alias and a dot. `q.id` refers to the `id` column from `question` table. When we've got table names like `wp_ai_quiz_tblquestions`, assigning an alias, like `q` can make the query easier to read (compared to qualifying column references it with a full table name). Qualifying ALL column references is best practice.